# Nokogiri 'not' selector

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Is there a way in Nokogiri to select all elements that don't match a selector. In jQuery I'd use:

```
:not(*[@class='someclass'])
```

However the following code gives me an xpath syntax error

```
dom = Nokogiri::HTML(@file)
dom.css(":not(*[@class='someclass'])")
```

Comment: the problem I was having was because I was adding quotes `'` to my class name, where it's just `:not(.someclass)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the syntax you are using, but this is basically xpath selector you want:

```
dom.xpath("//wherever/*[not (@class='someclass')]")
```

Comment: Is it also possible to do glob style matching on the 'someclass'?

Comment: I'm not sure, Nokogiri only supports xpath 1 I believe which is annoying. You can try using the contains function for substring matching: "//wherever/*[not (contains(@class, 'some'))]"

Comment: Nokogiri supports both CSS accessors and XPath very well. Everything is passed to libxml2 for parsing, so if libxml2 supports it Nokogiri should.

Comment: The syntax being used in the question is css, you're answering with xpath (which is perhaps why the syntax is unfamiliar to you).

Answer (score 12):

[In CSS3, :not() takes a selector like any other](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation), so it would be:

```
dom.css(":not(.someclass)")
```

(untested, but the selector is right)

Comment: Appreciate this; I was a bit confused because ":not('.someclass')" works in the browser, but for my selenium test I needed to remove the quotes inside the parenthesis

Comment: 8 years later, still works fine, doesn't work when adding quotes e.g. `:not('.someclass')` and works fine when chained e.g. `a:not(.someclass):not(:first-child):not(:last-child)`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to ton's answer, if you want to use two classes, that it would like this:

```
.local:not(.hide)
```